# Running a .net solution inside a .net solution

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a .net 4.5 mvc project, that sits inside a folder of a cms that is also made in .net

The routing in the outer .net cms is overruling routing of my mvc solution. I was told by technical staff for the cms that it is possible to tell the outer cms to get out of the way and let my solution do it's own routing, however I can't add a route.ignore to RouteConfig.cs in RegisterRoutes because I can't compile their software.

Is there a way I can make my application handle it's own routing? Possibly by editing the web.config of the higher level .net cms

Comment: @HarshBaid It's a client specific (closed-source) cms. The problem is not with the cms but just about adding a .net mvc project inside a .net project.

Comment: ok, Since you mentioned `I was told by technical staff for the cms that it is possible to tell the outer cms to get out of the way and let my solution do it's own routing` Ask the technical staff to add your routes to IgnoreList in the cms ?